# How do insert file with content resolver in Android?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-10.0, android-storage

I'm trying to insert audio file to shared storage in Android. I'm getting error on api 29(emulator).

**Error :**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Primary directory (invalid) not allowed for content://media/external_primary/audio/media; allowed directories are [Alarms, Music, Notifications, Podcasts, Ringtones]
```

My Code is:

```java
...
Uri collection = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) 
                ? MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
                : MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);

values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, targetFileName);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, targetFileDirPath);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 1);

resolver = getContentResolver();
uri = resolver.insert(collection, values); // error throws from here
outputStream = uri != null ? resolver.openOutputStream(uri) : null;
...
```

What is the cause of this error and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my earlier answer, as I missed that you were using `MediaStore.Audio.Media`. I am not completely certain why you are getting this message, but you might try adding one of the suggested base collections to your `RELATIVE_PATH`.

Comment: @CommonsWare you are right. The problem is about my RELATIVE_PATH(targetFileDirPath) . I solved changing relative path to "Music/My App Name". Thank you. If you add as answer for accept your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, `MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri()` does not return a directly-usable `Uri`, at least on Android 10+. It points to an abstract location for "audio", but you cannot write content directly to that `Uri`. Instead, you need to use `RELATIVE_PATH` to specify one of the supported collections (`Alarms`, `Music`, `Notifications`, `Podcasts`, `Ringtones`), and then any path that you want inside of there.

Note, though, that `RELATIVE_PATH` itself is new to Android 10. For Android 9 and older devices, I recommend just writing to the filesystem directly.

Answer (score -4):

{ Confirm usage of @CommnWare

values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + FILE_DIR);
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 1);
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, FILE_NAME);
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain");`enter code here`

ContentResolver resolver = _context.getContentResolver();
resolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY), values);
}